# extjs6 modern card layut

Tags: extjs, cardlayout

I am new in Extjs. I have a container with card layout with 3 sub views including a grid, a form for creating and a form for updating using route.

```
   items: [
         {xtype: 'feature-grid',id:'feature-grid},
         {xtype: 'create-form'},
         {xtype: 'update-form'}
    ],
```

it works well at the first time but when I change the route and switch to this route again this error appears:

```
Uncaught Error: DOM element with id feature-grid in Element cache is not the same as element in the DOM. Make sure to clean up Element instances using destroy()
```

and when I remove the id the save button in my create form doesnt add  record to the grid without any error!
my save button is like this:

```
var form = button.up('formpanel');
var values = form.getValues();
var user = Ext.create('App.model.User',values);
var cntr = this.getView('UserContainer')
var mainpanel = button.up('user-container');
var grid = mainpanel.down('grid');
grid.store.add(user);
form.reset();
this.redirectTo('users')
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using [routes](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.app.route.Route.html) so in this case first you need to check you view is already created or not. If view is already created then you can use that view otherwise you can create view.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2dn6)**, I have create a demo using [`cardlayout`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.layout.Card.html), [`grid`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html) and [`form`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.form.Panel.html). I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        //Define cotroller
        Ext.define('MainController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.maincontroller',

            routes: {
                'application/:node': 'onViewChange'
            },

            //this event will fire whenver routing will be changed
            onViewChange: function (xtype) {
                var view = this.getView(),
                    newNode = view.down(xtype);

                //if view is not crated then 1st created
                if (!newNode) {
                    newNode = Ext.create({
                        xtype: xtype
                    });
                }

                // is new view is form then first reset the form
                if (newNode.isXType('form')) {
                    newNode.reset();
                }
                // if new view type is update-form then load the record
                if (xtype == 'update-form') {
                    newNode.setRecord(this.record)
                    this.record = null;
                }

                //If view is created then directly set active that view
                view.setActiveItem(newNode);
            },

            //this event will fire when main view render
            onMainViewAfterRedner: function () {
                this.redirectTo('application/feature-grid');
            },
            //this event will fire when grid items clicked
            onGridItemClick: function (grid, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
                this.record = record;
                this.redirectTo('application/update-form');
            },

            //this event will fire when cancel button clicked
            onCancelButtonClick: function () {
                this.redirectTo('application/feature-grid');
            },

            //this event will fire when add new button clicked
            onAddNew: function () {
                this.redirectTo('application/create-form');
            },

            //this event will fire when save button clicked
            onSaveButtonClick: function (button) {
                var me = this,
                    form = button.up('formpanel'),
                    store = me.getView().down('grid').getStore(),
                    values = form.getValues();

                if (form.xtype == 'update-form') {
                    store.findRecord('id', values.id).set(values);
                } else {
                    if (values.name && values.email && values.phone) {
                        delete values.id;
                        store.add(values);
                    } else {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Info','Please enter form details');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                this.onCancelButtonClick();
            }
        });

        Ext.define('AppForm', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
            layout: 'vbox',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                //flex: 1,
                width: '100%',
                margin: '10 5',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                allowBlank: false
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'id',
                hidden: true
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                label: 'Name'
            }, {
                name: 'email',
                label: 'Email'
            }, {
                name: 'phone',
                label: 'Phone Number'
            }, {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'action',
                    margin: 5,
                    flex: 1
                },
                items: [{
                    text: 'Save',
                    formBind: true,
                    handler: 'onSaveButtonClick'
                }, {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: 'onCancelButtonClick'
                }]
            }]
        });

        //this create-form.
        Ext.define('CreateForm', {
            extend: 'AppForm',
            alias: 'widget.create-form',
            title: 'Create form'
        });

        //this update-form.
        Ext.define('UpdateForm', {
            extend: 'AppForm',
            alias: 'widget.update-form',
            title: 'Update form'
        });

        //this feature-grid.
        Ext.define('fGrid', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            alias: 'widget.feature-grid',
            title: 'User List grid',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                flex: 1,
                store: {
                    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Lisa',
                        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '555-111-1224'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Bart',
                        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '555-222-1234'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Homer',
                        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '555-222-1244'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Marge',
                        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '555-222-1254'
                    }]
                },
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone',
                    flex: 1
                }],
                listeners: {
                    itemtap: 'onGridItemClick'
                }
            }],
            tools: [{
                type: 'plus',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-plus',
                handler: 'onAddNew'
            }],
            flex: 1
        });

        //Define the main view form extending panel
        Ext.define('MainView', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            controller: 'maincontroller',
            alias: 'widget.mainview',
            layout: 'card',
            listeners: {
                painted: 'onMainViewAfterRedner'
            }
        });

        //this will create main view that is card layout
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'mainview',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            fullscreen: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much.It was helpful but there is a small difference between what I look for and this code. I want to see my grid in application and not application/feature-grid and it doesn't work yet

Comment: Can you put your full working efforts [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)? so I can try resolved.

Comment: can I ask you to email me? because it is full of folders and it's hard for me to put it there. yasi_m2009@yahoo.com

Comment: please your mail.

Comment: It worked well. Thank you. I want to route to create page with url but when I use /createform it first routes to grid. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I did't get the your requirement can you please explain again?

Comment: I cant access to create or edit in this card layout before loading grid. It means in first load when I use localhost:/create it route to grid first